# Using Calculated Fields with SQL Triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to write an SQL Trigger with the following approximate form:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableABSync ON TableA
FOR INSERT AS

INSERT INTO TableB
        (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    SELECT
        PK_ColA, ColB, ColC - ColD, ColE * TableB.Col3
    FROM inserted
```

So I'd like to use the newly generated Col3 to calculate Col4. Will I have to do this in stages?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you directly use something like :

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableABSync ON TableA
FOR INSERT AS

INSERT INTO TableB
        (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    SELECT
        PK_ColA, ColB, ColC - ColD, ColE *( TableB.ColC - TableB.ColD)
    FROM inserted
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The initial spec had confused me, but this is precisely the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with triggers or the insert - you can't reference a calculated value in the `SELECT` clause from within the same `SELECT` clause.

Maybe:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableABSync ON TableA
FOR INSERT AS

INSERT INTO TableB
        (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    SELECT
        PK_ColA, ColB, ColC - ColD as Col3, ColE * .Col3
    FROM
       (
          SELECT PK_ColA, ColB, ColC - ColD as Col3,ColE
          FROM inserted
       ) t
```